# NullPointerException when Mockito mocking ObjectOutputStream.writeObject?

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, objectoutputstream

I'm writing a jUnit test, checking what a class writes to ObjectOutputStream.

**Specifically, I'm checking that a class is calling writeObject with a certain type:**

```
ObjectOutputStream out = mock(ObjectOutputStream.class);

out.writeObject(new Something());

verify(out).writeObject(isA(Something.class));
```

But Java is complaining of a NullPointerException inside of `writeObject`.

What do I need to stub to fix this?

Comment: Have you already mentioned to Mockito that what needs to be done on out.writeObject? Please post your complete test case here.

Comment: Chances are the `out` variable is `null`.

Comment: @Blaine.. he is mocking the stream class and assigning it to out.. so it should not be null; but he needs to tell Mockito thhat what it should do, when a method call is done on mock object.

Comment: @gyan Correct. Any idea what I should stub?

Comment: @gyan, not at all.  He/she is only in knowing that it was called, not in providing any behaviour for when it DOES get called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't possible with Mockito. According to the [ObjectOutputStream javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeObject%28java.lang.Object%29), the `writeOutput` method is final:

```
public final void writeObject(Object obj) throws IOException
```

Internally, Mockito actually mocks these objects by creating a [Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html), which dynamically overrides ObjectOutputStream. Because the `writeObject` method is final, though, you aren't able to override or mock it and Java calls the original. This is listed as one of the [limitations of Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/FAQ#What_are_the_limitations_of_Mockito).

Though you may be able to verify against `writeObjectOverride`, your better bet is actually to refactor your code to use the interface [ObjectOutput](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutput.html) instead of ObjectOutputStream directly. ObjectOutputStream implements ObjectOutput, and Mockito can mock *any* method of an interface.

Comment: Could you add an example of how you did it @apennebaker ? I have the exact same problem, but not the insight to understand this answer and how to do it.